# Powershell with Selenium: Error: element not interactable

Tags: javascript, powershell, selenium

I need to update a textarea with a value.
The code below throws an error "element not interactable". This is because the textarea has "display:none". If I remove the word NONE manually and then run the script again, it works great and is able to set the value of the textarea.

```
$browser = Start-SeChrome
$url = "https://www.freepik.com/profile/login"
$browser.Navigate().GoToURL($url)

$CaptchaResponse = "03AGdBq27yHAQ62QjKrtg"
ForEach ($TextArea_Element in (Find-SeElement -Driver $browser -TagName TextArea))
   {
   if ($TextArea_Element.GetAttribute('id') -eq "g-recaptcha-response") {$TextArea_Element.SendKeys($CaptchaResponse)}   
   Break
   }
```

So the only option available is to use Javascript so that I can interact with the DOM directly (https://fijiaaron.wordpress.com/2018/01/29/how-to-access-elements-when-you-get-elementnotinteractableexception/). So I would have to do something like this:

```
$browser.executeScript("document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').value = $CaptchaResponse")
$browser.executeScript("___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0].L.L.callback($CaptchaResponse)")
```

But now I get a different set of errors: javascript error: Invalid or unexpected token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to edit your code as below to execute js with variable:

```
$browser.executeScript("document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').value = arguments[0];", $CaptchaResponse)
```

As same as first line,  you should extract the variable and replace to arguments[0]

```
$browser.executeScript("___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0].L.L.callback('arguments[0]');", $CaptchaResponse)
```

You can execute JS like this, use `arguments` to pass your variables into JavaScript:

```
$new_style = "display: block; left: 20px;"
$browser.executeScript("arguments[0].style='arguments[1]';", $element, $new_style)
```

Comment: Your command worked great for the first line. Can you also help with the second line. Sorry my knowledge of javascript is bad - $browser.executeScript("___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0].L.L.callback($CaptchaResponse)")

Comment: @hdsouza I edited my answer. Hope it's helpful for you :)

Comment: Thanks Yun. When I run the second command I get an error "Exception calling "ExecuteScript" with "2" argument(s): "javascript error: Cannot read property 'L' of undefined"

Comment: I'm not sure what this command do,  but I edited my answer for second command. Could you try again?

Comment: Maybe to make this simpler, how can I execute this JavaScript line "___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0]" using powershell and save to a variable. I have updated the question with a screenshot of what I see in google dev tools when I run the command